# why i use print function for a jpg fie it's not start with '\xff\xd8'

Tags: python, python-3.x

Recently I read a [book](https://github.com/yasoob/intermediatePython/blob/master/open_function.rst), there is some code snippet like this:

```
import io

with open('photo.jpg', 'rb') as inf:
    jpgdata = inf.read()

if jpgdata.startswith(b'\xff\xd8'):
    text = u'This is a JPEG file (%d bytes long)\n'
else:
    text = u'This is a random file (%d bytes long)\n'
```

I change the code like this:

```
import io  
with open('photo.jpg', 'rb') as inf:
    jpgdata = inf.read()

if jpgdata.startswith(b'\xff\xd8'):
    print("This is a JPEG file")       #change this line
else:
    print("This is not  a JPEG file") #change this line
```

output is:

[image]

where I print the **jpgdata** :

```
 import io  
with open('photo.jpg', 'rb') as inf:
    jpgdata = inf.read()
    print(jpgdata) #add this line 

if jpgdata.startswith(b'\xff\xd8'):
    print("This is a JPEG file")
else:
    print("This is not  a JPEG file")
```

I find the output is like this:
[image]

so, my question is why the **print function** does not start with the bytes FF D8?

Comment: Are you sure your terminal isn't deceiving you? Try printing e.g. `jpgdata[:16]`.

Comment: oh my god, i print the jpgdata[:16],the output is  **b'\xff\xd8\xff\xe0\x00\x10JFIF\x00\x01\x01\x01\x00H'**,so what is the different between them.@AKX

Comment: I bet there was just a carriage return somewhere further along the line, resetting the print cursor position to the start.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy That's incorrect. `print()` writes strings, not bytes; for bytes objects it prints the repr.

Answer (score 0):

To expand on my comment:

Based on the screenshot, the empty row between `import io` and the start of the output led me to think that the output isn't being drawn correctly (it'd probably otherwise have no empty row). On that note, I know some terminals, especially those based on web technologies as you seem to be using, have trouble rendering very long lines, and printing out a JPEG file's `repr()` definitely is a long line.

From there, we could test this hypothesis by only printing the first 16 bytes, slicing `jpgdata[:16]` -- and so, we can see the expected FFD8 marker is indeed there, it just wasn't being printed out correctly.

Comment: The OP's code wasn't even printing the `repr`, but copying the unmodified literal data direct to the terminal. Printing the repr of the full file may be huge and slow, but it wouldn't corrupt any reasonably correct terminal implementation.

Comment: Printing a bytes object prints its repr. You'll have to do something like `sys.stdout.buffer.write(x)` to write the bytes directly.

Comment: "the empty row between import io and the start of the output "--it caused by the [vsocde](https://code.visualstudio.com/).every cell's output will have an empty .you can find it in the two screenshoot

Answer (score 0):

Most files carry a 2-byte header called a "Magic Number" which basically specifies the file type.

[The magic number of JPEGs](https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-d&q=magic+number+jpeg) is "FFD8", so you can check if a file (likely) is a JPEG file by checking whether it starts with `"\xFF\xD8"`.

If it doesn't start with that number, you should probably print it out as debug, to check the rest of the header on whether it is JPEG-related. You could also have some further heuristic checks to see if it's mislabeled.